# Getting ****************************************** in vivo instead of url

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, logging, usb-debugging

can't print url and email in android logcat for other devices it works fine
2023-06-23 15:44:05.092  6896-7945  okhttp.OkHttpClient      I  --> GET *****************************************************************************

Want to print url and email to android logcat.

Comment: yeah that happens I don't know why but logcat doesn't print urls and emails , filter the string by removing  .com and then it would print the rest of email.

Comment: #VIVO device has lot of bugs for development. Its not recommended to use.